# how to do event hub event routing at scale based on custom logic

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

my application have multiple independent components which takes request/data over eventhub, do some processing and publish response data, which will be processed by another component (based on the event type).

I need to build a router, which will listen to event hubs of all the components and then based on event type and config value write the event to request event hub for next component.

Azure event grid has something similar for custom events, but i have to configure it from Azure portal and i can't configure from my code. I want routing to be my config driven, so that when new routes are added, it can be done through my app UI

Is azure funcitions a good option to build such a routing service, can i get high throughput and scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Grid has CLI, PowerShell, and SDK support in .Net, GO, Java, Python, Node, and Ruby - you can easily configure it from anywhere that suits you best!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/sdk-overview